# Ordering $n$ points in $\Bbb{R}^d$ so that every three consecutive points determine an acute angle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, permutations

> Let $x_1, \ldots ,x_n$ be distinct points in $\Bbb{R}^d$. Prove that there is a permutation $\sigma$ of $[n]$ such that the $\angle x_{\sigma(i−1)}x_{\sigma(i)}x_{\sigma(i+1)} < \pi/2$ for any $i = 2,\ldots, n−1$.

So I have got this question, and I am not able to understand what "a permutation $\sigma$ of $[n]$" mean? Can someone explain to me this question and provide some hints to approach it?

P.S. I have edited out some parts as it was a bit irrelevant.

Comment: Here $[n]$ denotes the index set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, so you need to prove that you can reorder the given points so that any three consecutive points enclose an acute angle.

Comment: @Berci Thanks for the clarification. I just went through some lexicography ordering permutation. I think somehow they are related.

Comment: Don't overcomplicate it, any permutation on the indices could do.

Comment: @Berci Thanks. I think I m getting it now. lemme try it.