# Showing that, for any point set in $\Bbb{R}^d$, it is possible to order them so that every consecutive three determine an acute angle

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, permutations

I am trying to solve this question.

> Let $F$ be a point set in $\mathbb R^d$ of size $n$. Prove that it is possible to denote the points of $F$ as $X_1,\dots, X_n$ in such way that, for any $i\in \{2,\dots, n-1\}$, the angle $\angle X_{i-1}X_iX_{i+1}$ is acute.

I think I have to use permutation for this but I am unable to relate to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks for the question. I have reconstructed the question I hope it is now understandable.

Comment: What is the "size" of a point in $\mathbb{R}^d$ ?

Comment: @coffeemath since these are points in $R^d$ I assume they will be d tuples. I have actually not thought about this point though. And nothing else has been mentioned.

Comment: If you just mean the point has $d$ coordinates, you needn't say anything about "size". Certainly not say size $n$ which would mean $n$ coordinates rather than $d.$ Actually it might be better to just say $F$ is a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ since you go on and mention the $n$ coordinates $F_k.$

Comment: OP posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3928940/sigmaσ-permutations) several days ago, without showing much work.

Comment: @coffeemath: It seems to me that "size" refers to the *set*, as in "a point-set [...] of *cardinality* $n$". And then the $X_k$ are the *members* of that set (that is, the $n$ points themselves), according to an appropriate order.

Comment: @Blue, strange! how come I can submit my answer succesfully after you have marked this as duplicate?

Comment: @Blue On more thought I see your point of view and agree. At least with that version it becomes an interesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct a polyline $x_1x_2\ldots x_n$ using following algorithm:

1. Among all pairs $u, v \in F$, there are pairs which maximize their
   distance. Pick any pair and call them $x_1, x_2$, we have:

$$|x_1 - x_2 | = \max\{ |u - v| : u, v \in F \}$$

2. For any $2 < k \le n$, let $F_k = F \setminus \{ x_1, \ldots, x_{k-1} \}$. Among all vertices in $F_k$, there are some which maximize the distance to $x_{k-1}$. Pick one of them and call it $x_k$, we have:
   $$|x_k - x_{k-1}| = \max\{ |u - x_{k-1} | : u \in F_k \}$$

For any $2 \le k \le n - 1$, let
$$a = |x_{k-1} - x_k|, b = |x_k - x_{k+1}|\;\text{ and }\;c = |x_{k-1} - x_{k+1}|$$
For $k = 2$, since $x_1x_2$ is a diameter of $F$, we have $a \ge c$.

For $k > 2$, since $x_{k+1} \in F_k$, by definition of $x_k$, $a \ge c$ again.

By cosine law, the angle $\theta_k \stackrel{def}{=} \angle x_{k-1}x_kx_{k+1}$ satisfies:

$$\cos\theta_k = \frac{a^2+b^2 - c^2}{2ab} = \frac{(a^2-c^2) + b^2}{2ab} \ge \frac{b}{2a} > 0$$
This implies $\theta_k < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and the polyline has an acute angle at $x_k$.

As a side note, since $x_1x_2$ is a diameter of $F$, if we prepend $x_0 \stackrel{def}{=} x_n$ to the polyline, the angle $\theta_1 = \angle x_0x_1x_2 = \angle x_nx_1x_2$ is also acute. This means as a closed polygonal chain, $x_1x_2\ldots x_n$ has at least $n-1$ acute angles.

Comment: I'd like to see visually how this works on five points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by four vertices of a square along with the center of the square. [that isn't my example (I think it is due to Calvin Lin in the linked question referenced in the close question duplicate claim.] but seems to me a counterexample to the possibility to always be able to permute the points.]

Comment: Sorry about the square bracket-parenthesis mess, tried to fix but too late...

Comment: @coffeemath $ACBDO$ where $O$ is the center, $ABCD$ are vertices of square ordered counterclockwisely. $\angle ACB = \angle CBD = 45^\circ$ while $\angle BDO = 0^\circ$

Comment: Thanks for the response, @achille. Make it clear Lin's example doesn't work. And +1 on answer if it registers.